# lru_cache for classmethod that depends on a class attribute (Python)

Tags: python, class-method, python-lru-cache

I have a Python classmethod `Test.test(x)` that produces expensive data, i.e. I would like to use functools.lru_cache as a wrapper. However, the output depends on a class attribute `Test.a` that can take a small number of different values. I would like to keep a cached version for each combination (a,x) of the attribute a and parameter x. I.e. I want the cache to work the usual way, as long as the attribute a is unchanged, but the method should be reevaluated once there is a change of the class attribute. How is this best achieved?

Here the code example:

```
from functools import lru_cache

class Test():
    a = 1

    def __new__(cls, a = 1):
        cls.a = a
        return super().__new__(cls)
    
    @classmethod
    @lru_cache(maxsize=32)
    def test(cls, x):
        return x * cls.a
    
print(Test.test(1),Test(2).test(1),Test.test(1))
```

Desired output (with lru_cache disabled): `1 2 2`

Output with lru_cache: `1 1 1`

Some clarifications:

- The attribute a only gets changed rarely, hence it doesn't really matter whether there is a cached copy for each combination (a,x), or whether the cache is reset whenever the value of a changes.
- The test method *must* be implemented that way as a classmethod (since it inherits from an abstract class which I cannot change).
- Other ways to pass the value of a to the method are at least undesired. `Test(a).test(x)` would be the correct way in which similar functions of the project are called.

Comment: Add a new method that takes both `a` and `x` as parameters, and apply `@lru_cache` to that.  Your `Test.test()` would then just be a call to that method, with no cacheing of its own.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks! I was thinking way too complicated about this. (Was aiming at something like https://gist.github.com/z0u/9df24dda2b1fe0613a85e7349d5f7d62 but a dummy method that is way easier.)